# Does KiCad no longer support THT footprints for home soldering of pin headers?

Tags: kicad, footprint, through-hole, pin-headers

I cannot find any connector that will simply allow me to make a PCB with THT holes for me to solder my own pin headers. The best I can find online is this [link](https://forum.kicad.info/t/header-pin-holes/27489) which identifies parts which I cannot find in KiCad 6. Yes I know it's probably time to update but before I relearn KiCad I'd just like to complete a design. Is there a ready-made library I'm missing? It just seems such a straightforward ask as there are THT hole-only footprints available for capacitors, resistors, 74xx chips etc but apparently none for pin headers.

Comment: No but thanks anyway. I want a simple footprint with soldering holes ready for me to solder the pin headers.

Answer (score 3):

KiCAD does include pin header footprints.  As of the current version they're under "Connector_Pinheader_":

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found that exact footprint, but in the 3D-Viewer it shows as a set of pre-soldered pin headers, which is not what I want. I want a row of holes so I can solder my own pin headers, be that male or female, as and when required.

Comment: @Hektor The fact that the part has a 3d model doesn't mean that it will be supplied with that soldered there. If you order a PCB, you will get just the PCB, and if you order assembly you will have to work out what parts do and do not get assembled with the assembly house; KiCad has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Hektor That footprint is exactly what you're looking for. The 3D model is not relevant here.

Comment: @Hearth Hopefully that will solve the problem then, I'll check with the PCB manufacturer, I just saw that when I uploaded the gerber files for a 5cm x 5cm board, the price had quadrupled since a similarly uncomplicated board ordered 2 weeks ago, so I assumed they were planning to solder the headers on. I'll check and report back here to confirm.

Comment: @Hektor:  A PC board shop will not install parts on the bare PC board, unless they provide a PCB assembly service, and you ask them to assemble the board (then you have to provide a parts list and assembly instructions).  Also, you can make your own footprints to suit your needs - the footprint editor is not hard to use, and, at some point, you WILL need to create your own footprints for some parts.

Comment: If you want to be sure (in case you do use a contract assembler service), you can always just mark that specific component location as "Do Not Populate" (DNP) in the part attributes.

Comment: I can't decide if a board fab populating your boards without asking or charging you would be a good or a bad thing.

Comment: @Hektor:  When you do use KiCad-supplied footprints check to be sure that the footprint you choose matches the part you want t use.  Note that the footprints that user1850479 shows above has the pins on 2.00 mm centers - you likely want something that has the pins on 2.54 mm (0.1 inch) centers.  Also confirm that the hole size is appropriate for your part.

Comment: @Hektor It's more likely that the price quadrupled because of something that's actually in the gerber files--perhaps your minimum trace width/spacing is smaller than before, or you have some very small vias, or something. If you're confused about the price, ask your representative at the fab about why it's priced the way it is.

Comment: @Hearth Turned out that was the base setup fee at JLCPCB, which I thought wouldn't be so steep for simply soldering 20 or so decoupling caps, but actually it was assuming I wanted the (Extended Part) Pin Headers adding too.

Comment: So yes, after re-uploading the board and not checking any Assembly links, the Pin Header footprint given by Connector_PinHeader_2.54mm:PinHeader_1x02_P2.54mm_Vertical and such like does only result in a THT footprint when the fab produces the board.